# Spring PropertySource not working in JUnit Test

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, junit, spring-4

I am facing issue while running JUnit test case.

Problem is,
When I run application as web application then `@PropertySource` works fine by injecting all properties from xml file but when I run the application as JUnit then I am getting error as "Could not resolve placeholder".

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:resources/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:resources/spring-mvc-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

DAO Class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:resources/shore-dal_queries.xml")
public class SpringShoreDao extends SpringBaseDao implements ShoreDao {

    @Value("${shore.getAllShores}")
    private String getShoresQuery;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<List<Shore>> getAllShores() throws DataAccessException {
        Optional<List<Shore>> shoreList = null;
        try {
            List<Shore> tempList = (getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(getShoresQuery, new ShoreRowMapper()));
            shoreList = Optional.of(tempList);
        }
        catch (org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException e) {
        }
        return shoreList;
    }
}
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="shore.getAllShores">
        <![CDATA[
            SELECT shoreID, shoreName, isActive, updatedBy, updatedDate, createdBy, createdDate
            FROM shore
        ]]>
    </entry>
</properties>
```

JUnit Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:resources/applicationContext.xml",
        "classpath:resources/spring-mvc-context.xml"})
public class SpringShoreDaoTest {


    @Autowired
    ShoreDao shoreDao; 

    @Test
    public void testGetAllShores() throws DataAccessException {
        List<Shore> listShore= shoreDao.getAllShores();
        ............  
    }
}
```

spring-mvc-context.xml

```
  <annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.him.utmc" />     
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/db.properties"/>
... DB related beans
```

When I run the JUnit Test File, I am getting exception as,

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'shore.getAllShores' in string value "${shore.getAllShores}"
```

while everything works fine when I run the same project as Web Application.

Comment: I don't see how your test is related to the other files you've posted. Why did you post web.xml? What are the two `applicationContext.xml` and `spring-mvc-context.xml`?

Comment: added that 2 files as well. I am not getting why JUnit is not able to autowire fields as I am loading that class

Answer (score 1):

You can define `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in test configuration and set your `resources/shore-dal_queries.xml` as resource to it (there is nice example [here](https://gist.github.com/danlangford/3418696)).

So try something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class SpringShoreDaoTest {

    @Configuration
    @ImportResource({"classpath:resources/applicationContext.xml",
    "classpath:resources/spring-mvc-context.xml"})   
    static class someConfig {

        // because @PropertySource doesnt work in annotation only land
        @Bean
        public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propConfig() {
            PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc =  new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
            ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("resources/shore-dal_queries.xml"));
            return ppc;
        }

        @Bean
        public SpringShoreDao springShoreDao() {
            //probably you do not need this bean since you have component scan in applicationContext 
            return new SpringShoreDao();
        }
    }


    @Autowired
    SpringShoreDao springShoreDao; 

    @Test
    public void testGetAllShores() throws DataAccessException {
        List<Shore> listShore= shoreDao.getAllShores();
        ............  
    }
}
```

Comment: I have removed `applicationContext.xml` and `spring-mvc-context.xml` because I did not see how they are connected to dao class alone and why they are needed. If you need them than define `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in test only xml and add it on to to `@ContextConfiguration` after two xml resources.

Comment: I required it as db configuration is present in applicationContext.xml and same DAO class use to fetch data. Can you please modify the code snippet by including that file as I am not getting "in test only xml"

Comment: Can you try with `@ImportResource` as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365366/mixing-xml-and-java-config-with-spring

Comment: I tried you mentioned but still error persist. In example link, it has to inject values in test class but i don't want to inject in test class. Why @PropertySource in not working in test case execution.

Comment: It is not working with @ImportResource. I am missing something obvious it seems.

Comment: Ahh, you annotated dao class as `@Configuration` which is odd... And you redefine PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean each time. You should have configuration class which defines PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, properties etc and defines SpringShoreDao as component which uses only `@Value` injected, that would be better design and you would test easily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73039/discussion-between-nenad-bozic-and-jayesh).