# how to set ProtocolVersion when using spring data cassandra xml config

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

We are trying to upgrade DSE from 4.6 to 4.8.11 but we are facing version not supportable issue when connecting with client driver version 2.1.6. upgrade is happening in rolling fashion and we are getting com.datastax.driver.core.UnsupportedProtocolVersionException. After triaging, it looks like we need to specify protocol version to be used. Currently we connect to Cassandra using spring data Cassandra jar (1.3.2.RELEASE) but looks like XML config doesn't have option to set protocol version. Any help ?

This is what we want to achieve:

Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("x.x.x.x").withProtocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.V2).build();

http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/native_protocol/#protocol-version-with-mixed-clusters

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and no:

- Configuration of `ProtocolVersion` [was introduced with version 1.5](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-231).
- It's not possible to set `ProtocolVersion` through namespace config `<cassandra:cluster port=… />`.
- It's possible to set `ProtocolVersion` on `CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean` using Spring Data for Apache Cassandra 1.5. You can reference `CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean` from your XML config (`<bean class="o.s.c.c.CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean">…</bean>`) but you won't be able to benefit from the improved namespace configuration support.

Ideally, switch for `CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean` to Java-config. You can mix XML and JavaConfig.

References:

- [Mixing xml and java config with spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365366/mixing-xml-and-java-config-with-spring)
- [Mkyong: Spring – Mixing XML and JavaConfig](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-mixing-xml-and-javaconfig/)