# spring mvc interceptor with java configuration not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring MVC project and now changing the configuration from `.xml` to `.java`. For now i am facing an issue with interceptors.

These Interceptors work fine with `.xml` configuration but not working in `.java` configuration.

Here is the `.xml` code that works fine.

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>


    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:validation</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
   <!-- Interceptors work with the following xml configuration -->
   <!-- ======================================================= -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
            <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/**"/>
            <bean class="com.qsa.account.interceptors.CommonInterceptor"/>
        </mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/signup"/>
            <mvc:mapping path="/login"/>
            <bean id="redirectInterceptor" class="com.qsa.account.interceptors.RedirectInterceptor"></bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>

   <!-- ======================================================= -->    

        <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"></bean>
</beans>
```

And `.java` configuration are give as follows .When i comment the `.xml` configuration the interceptors don't get hit.

```
import com.qsa.account.interceptors.CommonInterceptor;
import com.qsa.account.interceptors.RedirectInterceptor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CommonInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/resources/**");
        registry.addInterceptor(new RedirectInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/login", "/signup");
    }
}
```

And security configuraton as

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

//TODO: Interceptors are currently configured in xml. Configuration should be done in java.

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/login*", "/signup/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/AccessControl/users").hasAuthority("AccessControl_users")
                .antMatchers("/AccessControl/manageUser").hasAuthority("AccessControl_manageUser")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

}
```

For `.java` configuraton the interceptors get registered when tomcat starts but not get hits after.

Comment: Are you actually loading the java configuration?

Comment: Yes, During the tomcat startup, the break point hits where the interceptors are registered.

Comment: Also what do you comment? You shouldn't be loading the xml anymore.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing [xml and java configs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365366/mixing-xml-and-java-config-with-spring). Try to add `@ImportResource({"classpath:my-mvc-config.xml"})`