# Spring Security - How to mix xml <security:http> and Java SecurityFilterChain declaration configurations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Working on an application that was using XML Schema-based Spring configuration only, I'm slowly introducing Java based configuration.

Unfortunately I'm not able to use Spring Security `html` xml element and Java based `SecurityFilterChain` configuration at the same time.

When I inspect the `filterChains` list in the `FilterChainProxy`, it only contains the filter chains from the xml configuration. Despite the Java method creating the `SecurityFilterChain` bean being called, this filter chain is not added to the `FilterChainProxy`.

If I remove the `html` elements from the xml configuration, the `SecurityFilterChain` from the Java configuration is added to the `FilterChainProxy` and called as expected.

Spring versions I'm using:

- Spring Framework: 5.3.16
- Spring Security: 5.6.2

Here is the xml configuration and Java configuration I'm trying to use simultaneously:

```html
<bean id="mySecurityConfig" class="com.xxx.SecurityConfiguration"/>

<http pattern="/style/**" security="none"/>
```

```java
    package com.xxx;
    
    [...]
    
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfiguration {
      
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/app/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                      .antMatchers("/app/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                      .anyRequest().denyAll()
                    )
                .addFilterBefore(anotherFilter(), Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class);
            return http.build();
        }
    
       [...]
    }
```

web.xml

```html
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Did I make a mistake, is there a way to achieve what I want, or is it simply not possible ?

Comment: Why do you want both configurations? It is unlikely that having both `http` XML and the Java Configuration work together since they configure the same thing.

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio To give you some context, the component I'm working on is a library used by most of the Java applications developed by my company. I'd like to move smoothly from xml based configuration to Java based configuration to limit impacts on depending applications.

Our xml configuration already contains multiple `http` elements, most of them are out of the scope of my current task and will be left untouched.
It left me with two choices : stick with the xml configuration only, or find a way to have both configuration styles working together.

Comment: Have you tried using the `@ImportResource` annotation? This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365366/mixing-xml-and-java-config-with-spring

Comment: @Marcus Thanks for this suggestion, but in my case it is the xml configuration that "imports" the Java configuration `<bean id="mySecurityConfig" class="com.xxx.SecurityConfiguration"/>`.  Appart from the SecurityFilterChain configuration, I don't have issues mixing xml and Java config. The `filterChain` method from the Java configuration is called as I would expect (and other beans are created and added to the Spring context).

Comment: It would be great if you open an issue in the Spring Security repository with a minimal, reproducible sample so we can check if it is not a bug with the configuration

Comment: @Marcus I created the following issue and linked a minimal sample [https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11108](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11108)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit: @rwinch [solution posted here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11108#issuecomment-1113608990)

> You can combine the XML and Java Configuration and exposes it as a
> different bean name using something like this:

```java
    @Configuration
    public class AggregateSpringSecurityConfiguration {
        public static final String AGGREGATE_SPRING_SECURITY_FILTER_CHAIN_ID = "aggregateSpringSecurityFilterChain";
    
        /**
         * Provide a new FilterChainProxy that contains both XML and Java Configuration
         * @param webSecurityConfiguration
         * @return
         * @throws Exception
         */
        @Bean(AGGREGATE_SPRING_SECURITY_FILTER_CHAIN_ID)
        Filter aggregateSpringSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration webSecurityConfiguration) throws Exception {
            FilterChainProxy javaConfigFcp = (FilterChainProxy) webSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain();
            return new FilterChainProxy(javaConfigFcp.getFilterChains());
        }
    
    }
```

> Then ensure your XML configuration picks it up:

```xml
    <bean id="aggregateConfiguration" class="testapp.AggregateSpringSecurityConfiguration" />
    Finally, you need to update your web.xml to use the bean named aggregateSpringSecurityFilterChain instead of springSecurityFilterChain.
    
        <filter>
            <!-- matches AggregateSpringSecurityConfiguration.AGGREGATE_SPRING_SECURITY_FILTER_CHAIN_ID -->
            <filter-name>aggregateSpringSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
    
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>aggregateSpringSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

---

#### Initial workaround

Until better solution, it is possible to use the workaround below (if really needed). It adds the missing `SecurityFilterChain` to the `FilterChainProxy` once Spring Application context is initialized.
I implemented it against Spring Security **5.6.2**. Since it uses reflection, it might break after any upgrade of Spring Security version.

```java
    /**
     * This class is a workaround to allow declaring SecurityFilterChain using xml
     * configuration and Java configuration. It listens to the Spring Application
     * context events ContextRefreshedEvent and add SecurityFilterChain beans,
     * declared in the Java configuration, to the FilterChainProxy.
     */
    @Configuration
    public static class MissingSecurityFilterChainsInitializer {
        
        private FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy;
    
        private List<SecurityFilterChain> filterChains;
    
        /**
         * @param filterChainProxy
         * @param myFilter
         */
        public MissingSecurityFilterChainsInitializer(FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy,
                List<SecurityFilterChain> myFilterChains) {
            super();
            this.filterChainProxy = filterChainProxy;
            this.filterChains = myFilterChains;
        }
    
        /**
         * Method listening to the Spring Application context initialization, detects
         * missing SecurityFilterChain from the FilterChainProxy and add the missing
         * chains to the FilterChainProxy.
         * 
         * @param ctxRefreshed
         */
        @EventListener
        public void handleContextRefreshEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent ctxRefreshed) {
            List<SecurityFilterChain> missingChains = filterChains.stream()
                    .filter(chain -> !filterChainProxy.getFilterChains().contains(chain)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
            if (missingChains.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
    
            try {
                Field filterChainsField = filterChainProxy.getClass().getDeclaredField("filterChains");
                boolean accessibleStatus = filterChainsField.isAccessible();
                try {
                    filterChainsField.setAccessible(true);
                    List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = (List<SecurityFilterChain>) filterChainsField
                            .get(filterChainProxy);
                    if (chains == null) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(
                                "Unable to add the missing security filter chains to the existing filter chains list of the FilterChainProxy. The list from the FilterChainProxy is null");
                    }
                    missingChains.forEach(chain -> chains.add(chain));
                } finally {
                    filterChainsField.setAccessible(accessibleStatus);
                }
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Unable to add the missing security filter chains to the existing filter chains list of the FilterChainProxy: "
                                + e.getMessage(),
                        e);
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, mixing up Java bean configurations with XML configurations never work. We have to either use XML based or Java based configurations. I was trying to configure Content Security Policy in this way https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csp while I was already having implemented XML bean configurations.
It wasn't able to find httpSecurity bean to initialize no matter what. So I followed this way https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/spring-content-security-policy-guide-what-it-is-and-how-to-enable-it/#xml and added it to my applicationContext.xml

Answer (score -1):

filters are created, maintained, and destroyed by a Servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty. You declare filters in web.xml, and the web container initializes them by calling their init(FilterConfig config) method.  This filter then delegates the actual pre-processing and post-processing task to Spring aware Filter implementations provided by the Spring Security framework.

Every time a request or response comes and matches the URL pattern of the filter, then the Servlet container calls the  DelegatingFilterProxy's `doFilter()` method for the request and response filtering.

This method has access to ServletRequest, ServletResponse, and a FilterChain object, which means it can modify request headers, response headers, and response body before sending the request to Servlet or response to Client. The FilterChain object is used to route the request to another filter in the chain for further processing.

Read more: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/05/how-to-enable-spring-security-in-java-web-application.html#ixzz7QWQrVPCb